# '\0' character in a while loop at c

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array, while-loop, escaping

I want to make a function which takes an array full of strings and counts the words. I don't think that my code in the pic is wrong. Everytime a blank appears it is counted. BUT when a `'\0'` character shows up, the `while` loop doesn't do anything. Is something I don't know?

```
int Number(char w[][20]) {
    int i, counter, j;
    counter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        j = 0;
        do {
            if ((w[i][j] == '\0') || (w[i][j] == ' '))
                ++counter;
            j++;
        } while (w[i][j] != '\0');
        printf("counter=%d\n", counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: If a string is "empty" that is, comprising only `"\0"` then `\0` would be counted, but otherwise the `do .. while()` loop condition excludes `\0` from being considered. I suggest a `while() {...}` loop instead. Think about "when a `\0` character shows up". It isn't a character *within* a C string but its end marker.

Comment: Well the loop stops when it gets to a \0 character, so why do you think it would be counted?

Comment: The while loop doesn't work.If I don't put anything in the 2-d array in a line then the while won't be executed at all...I tried it though before I write in the forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems in your code:

- if a line does not have characters (starts with a `'\0'`), you increment `j` before testing for the end of string. Do not use `do`/`while` loops, they are error prone, and this bug is a classic one.
- you merely count the number of spaces: this is not the same as the number of words because there could be multiple spaces between 2 words or at the start or end of the line etc. You should instead count the number of transitions from space to non-space, starting from space.

Here is a simple implementation for your 2D array:

```
int Number(char w[][20]) {
    int i, j, counter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        char c, last = ' ';
        for (j = 0; (c = w[i][j]) != '\0'; j++) {
            if (last == ' ' && c != ' ')
                counter++;
            last = c;
        }
    }
    printf("counter=%d\n", counter);
}
```

Comment: You are correct.In a full scale-program that is necessary.Your approach is smarter than mine and I will rewrite my function.I won't know why the damn escape integer '\0' ends my do...while loop before the end of it but I will have a better and more logic program.Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working version of your code, and a test program.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int wc(const char *str)
{
    int count = 0;
    bool inword = false;

    char c;
    while ((c = *str++) != '\0')
    {
        if (c == ' ')
            inword = false;
        else
        {
            if (inword == false)
                count++;
            inword = true;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

static void Number(const char *tests[], int num_tests)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num_tests; i++)
        printf("%d: [%s]\n", wc(tests[i]), tests[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *tests[] =
    {
        "",
        " ",
        "  ",
        "a",
        "a b",
        " a b ",
        "  ab  cd  ",
        "The quick brown  fox jumps  over   the  lazy     dog.",
        "      The quick brown  fox jumps  over   the  lazy     dog.    ",
    };
    enum { NUM_TESTS = sizeof(tests) / sizeof(tests[0]) };
    Number(tests, NUM_TESTS);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that your `Number()` function does two jobs — and should only do one, delegating the other to a separate function.  It both counts the words in a single string and prints related information.  I delegate the word counting to a separate function `wc()`, which greatly simplifies the code in `Number()` — almost to the point that the function isn't needed.  Note, too, that my version of `Number()` is told the number of entries the array it is working on, rather than relying on a magic number like `4`.  Note that the output from my code allows you to check it for accuracy.  Simply printing the output number doesn't allow you to check for accuracy so easily; you have to look at the code to see what the numbers mean.  Note that your `Number()` function is defined to return an `int` but doesn't actually do so.  This version is defined not to return anything, and it doesn't.

The output from the code is:

```
0: []
0: [ ]
0: [  ]
1: [a]
2: [a b]
2: [ a b ]
2: [  ab  cd  ]
9: [The quick brown  fox jumps  over   the  lazy     dog.]
9: [      The quick brown  fox jumps  over   the  lazy     dog.    ]
```

Obviously, you could refine the space testing using the `isblank()` or `isspace()` macros (functions) from `<ctype.h>` if you wished, or define the boundary between word and not-word in other ways.  The basic concept is reliable, though, across fairly perverse sequences of blanks and words.

If you really want a 2D array of characters, it is not hard to write the code to work with that, though the 'lazy dog' strings will have to be reduced to fit into `char data[][20]` cleanly.  The basic ideas remain the same — and the `wc()` function doesn't change.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int wc(const char *str)
{
    int count = 0;
    bool inword = false;

    char c;
    while ((c = *str++) != '\0')
    {
        if (c == ' ')
            inword = false;
        else
        {
            if (inword == false)
                count++;
            inword = true;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

static void Number(const char tests[][20], int num_tests)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num_tests; i++)
        printf("%d: [%s]\n", wc(tests[i]), tests[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
    const char tests[][20] =
    {
        "",
        " ",
        "  ",
        "a",
        "a b",
        " a b ",
        "  ab  cd  ",
        "The quick brown fox",
        "  jumps   over     ",
        "  the  lazy  dog   ",
    };
    enum { NUM_TESTS = sizeof(tests) / sizeof(tests[0]) };
    Number(tests, NUM_TESTS);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0: []
0: [ ]
0: [  ]
1: [a]
2: [a b]
2: [ a b ]
2: [  ab  cd  ]
4: [The quick brown fox]
2: [  jumps   over     ]
3: [  the  lazy  dog   ]
```

Tests like the `"  ab  cd  "` example (with double blanks at the start, middle and end) are often very good ones for pushing edge cases — in more contexts than just word counting.  Many a shell script will not correctly handle arguments like that string, for example.

Comment: you are absolutely right inthe fact that the philosophy of my function calulates ' ' and word must change.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - The first principle of programming is: divide and conquer
 - The second is: use  a loop to iterate
So:
```

---

```
unsigned count_words(char*str)
{
unsigned len, words;

for(len=words=0; *str; str++){
        if(*str == ' ') if(len) {words++; len=0;}
        else len += 1;
        }

if (len) {words++; }
return words;
}
```

---

Now, call this function for any of your strings, adding the results.